# I am trying to compile a tex file, but I get package pdftex.def error file not found

Tags: pdftex

I have been written a bachelor's degree project report using Texstudio and working on Windows. Here everything was working properly, so I have uploaded this files to Dropbox in order to be used in Ubuntu 14.04. However, when I tried to compile this project, I got an error that says "the package pdftext.def error file was not found".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After checking the log I double click on one message, and I discover that a file was missing, so I look for this file in the directory it was supposed to be, and it was there. The problem was that the file was let's say image1.JPG instead of image1.jpg. I am currently now using Ubuntu, and this was kind of weird because the same project with no modifications works correctly on Windows, but I had to change JPG to jpg in order to have it working on Ubuntu.

Comment: `.JPG` is supported by `pdftex.def` since version 2006/08/14 v0.03t. The file systems under Windows are usually case insensitive, whereas Linux file systems are case sensitive.